# Mapping RDD column based on value of another column in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a beginner here. I'm working with Spark 2.4.4 and Scala.

I have an RDD with three columns with the first entry like this:

```
(String, Double, String) = (100,10,neg)
```

The RDD has thousands of entries. I want to change the value of the double to a negative value when there is 'neg' in the same row and do nothing when there is any other phrase. I want to get the following output:

```
(String, Double) = (100,-10)
```

I figured the map function would work for this to create a new RDD, but if there is another option, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have all the required data on the same item, you can use `map` to make your data transformations.

```
val yourRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    ("10", 2.0, "neg"),
    ("50", 6.0, "other"),
    ("40", -5.0, "neg"),
    ("100", 1.0, ""))) // Sample data
// org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Double, String)]

val updatedRDD = yourRDD.map(item=>{
  val tag = item._3 // position of your tag 
  val outputValue = if(tag.equals("neg") && item._2>0) item._2 * -1 // only if your tag is 'neg' and the value is possitive
                else item._2 
  (item._1 ,outputValue)
})
// Output data: ((10,-2.0), (50,6.0), (40,-5.0), (100,1.0))
```